# Adding new top level UIView to Storyboard and preserving other UIView constraints

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have several `UIViews` on a storyboard with autolayout constraints attached to them, in the below example hierarchy:

```
View A

View B

— View B1

— View B2

View C
```

I am wanting to insert another UIView at the top level and drag into that all the other UIViews on the Storyboard but without messing up the constraints, for example:

```
View NEW

— View A

— View B

— — View B1

— — View B2

— View C
```

So far when dragging all `UIViews` into the new top level `UIView`, the constraints are broken and messed up.

Question:

1 - What are the techniques for preserving all constraints on the Storyboard when in the process of moving `UIViews` into another `UIView`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no techniques. no other way than to reset those.

Good news is that the sub-views will not get messy. e.g. B1 and B2 will preserving there constraints.

**A workaround:**

Create a temporery ViewController copy your root view to it. Then, delete all your subviews from the original ViewController (A,B,C). re-paste the root view, you copied to your original controller.
Now you have an extra view that contains all view. use it as your new view.

**Note:** A copy and paste for the root view to the same viewcontrller may prevent losing outlets.

I just try it. and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just gave it a go, but noticed that when doing that, it managed to removed all references. Might need to link them back to the code and see if it works as intended.